# ASP.NET MVC model binder not parsing ISO DateTime correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I've been trying to post a form to my controller:

```
Id=0&ReportDate=2010-08-09T00%3A00%3A00&SampleText=Save
```

That's the XHR post that is sent, my controller picks up all the properties except ReportDate, instead setting it to the .NET epoch DateTime. Any ideas?

Edit: If I set another variable, `ReportDateString`, send the string to the controller and do a `DateTime.Parse()`, it works fine. However, I'd really like to be able to bind the DateTime directly as this feels hacky.

Edit 2: Hereis my controller code:

```
public void CreateTest(MyObject myObject) {
    myObjectRepository.Update(rootObject);          
}
```

And my object:

```
public class MyObject {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SampleText{ get; set; }
    public DateTime ReportDate { get; set; }
}
```

If I set a debug, I can see that the model binder successfully binds all the properties on my post except the DateTime which it sets to the epoch date.

Edit 3:
Form:

```
<form id="testform" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="Id" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="ReportDate" value="2010-08-09T00-00-00" />
<input type="text" name="SampleText" value="Test"/>
<button id="saveButton">Save</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#saveButton')live('click', function(e) {
 $.post('CreateTest', $('#testform').serialize())
});
```

Comment: could you post the Controlleraction-code?

Comment: May an i18n issue. So that the Date could not converted because of a wrong date format.

Comment: Any pointers on debugging i18n issues?

Comment: I can almost assure you that this is not an i18n issue since the format yyyy-mm-ddThh:MM:ss is an internationally recognized DateTime. This point is further proven in the fact that DateTime.Parse works on the string-representation of the datetime. Post the code for your HTML-form (and/or submit-mechanism). I'm pretty sure this problem has a simple solution..  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine for me:

```
 public void Test2(DateTime ReportDate, string SampleText, int Id)
```

with the url:

```
/Home/Test2?Id=0&ReportDate=2010-08-09T00:00:00&SampleText=Save
```

ReportDate is then {09.08.2010 00:00:00} when I break in my code...

Edit - Additional Code:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   { %>
    <%= Html.Hidden("ReportDate", "2010-08-09T00:00:00") %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("SampleText", "Save") %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("Id", "1") %>
    <input type="submit" />
<%} %>
```

I also tried the following with the same result:

```
<form id="testForm">
    <%= Html.Hidden("ReportDate", "2010-08-09T00:00:00") %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("SampleText", "Save") %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("Id", "1") %>
    <a href="#" id="submitform">Submit!</a>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submitform").click(function () {
        $.post("/Home/Test2", $("#testForm").serialize());
    });

</script>
```

And this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test2(MyObject myObject) {
    return View();
}
```

Where MyObject is a copy/paste from your original question..

Comment: How are you preventing the colons from changing to %3? That might be the difference. I'm serializing a form and the ReportDate is a hidden input field.

Comment: Updated the post with the form-code I've used... I don't do anything else than what you see in the post, so it's weird that it doesn't work for you....

Comment: it doesn't matter that colons change to %3 in the post, because that's the way HTTP encoding works... for instance a space becomes %20 in an URL... So that's not your problem... I would guess your problem might be in the actual form html-code..

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that it decodes prior to the model binding, so the HTTP encoding wouldn't be the issue.

Comment: I'll take you up on your Occam's razor bet, I've posted my form and javascript, pretty identical to yours. I can confirm it does post the string at the top of my question (using Firebug and Fiddler, both produce that). All the other values get bound to the object.

Comment: As Occam's razor says - The simplest solution is usually the right one: in <input type="hidden" name="ReportDate" value="2010-08-09T00-00-00" /> try to replace the hyphens in the timedesignation with colons ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is not that tricky, you need to add cultural settings to your webconfig. This should solve your problem. In my case it is TR, you can try adding yours

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    **<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="tr-TR" uiCulture="tr-TR" />**
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```